# Not undestanding generics in F#

Tags: f#

Let's assume this code:

```
let ToLower x = (string x).ToLower()
```

I can call it with:

```
ToLower 3
```

or:

```
ToLower 3.0
```

but not both since the first caller defines the type.
so, I did this change, with my C# knowledge of generics:

```
let ToLower (x : 'a) = (string x).ToLower()
```

but same problem, it looks like the first caller is specializing the generic and that's it.

I'm looking for a solution where the compiler will generate n versions of the assignment, as needed based on the use cases.

What is the proper way to achieve this in F#?

Comment: Make `ToLower` inline

Comment: I understand it fixes the problem, but I'm trying to understand how F# handles generics vs. C# in this case. In C# I can declare a generic method and the compiler will instantiate several versions as needed. In F# I guess it's done differently. I don't understand (yes, I read the docs) ToLower<'a> x vs ToLower (x:'a) syntax either

Comment: You can't write this as a single method in C# either. You can write _two_ methods, one that takes an `int` and one that takes a `float`, and then have the compiler choose the one you want when you call it, but you still have to write two methods. In F# you can't overload methods like this because of the type inference, which is a minor annoyance, but that's the only difference I see here.

Comment: You can use statically resolved type parameters on inline functions though. I believe the documentation you're looking for is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters

Comment: @glennsl: yes that page is what I needed! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# type inference uses constraint solving where the use of a function later in the code can affect the type.

This is however only ever a problem when you are using some built-in primitives such as `+` or `string`, which are generic, but have special meaning for certain types. For those, you can use `inline` (in which case, the code gets inlined and the compiler can handle the special meanings in the place where they are used). If you do not use `inline`, the compiler will fix the type when you first use the function.

1. If you just define the function and never use it anywhere, then you get a type `obj -> string`. This is because the compiler used `obj` as the default type when there were no other constraints.
2. If you define the function and call it with `ToLower 3`, the compiler adds a constraint that restricts the argument type to be `int` (but then you cannot use it with anything else).

The case of `string` is a bit odd, because you can convert any value to string - but if you want to do this for any value, you have to `box` it first. Boxing is something that can be done on a generic value, so in this case, you can define this as a generic function:

```
let ToLower (x:'a) = (string (box x)).ToLower()
ToLower 3.0
ToLower 3
```

This works because the type of `box` is `'a -> obj` without any other caveats (unlike the type of `string` which is `'a -> string`, but with special handling of certain type parameters).